# extract item from string based on a pattern

Tags: r

I have some strings like:

```
myfun(expr1, expr2)*expr3
```

and want to extract `expr1` and `expr2` (They can be any expression)，`myfun` is a fixed function name.

To give two examples:

1. myfun((a+b)*c, 5)×var2
   I want to extract: (a+b)*c and 5
2. pmin(var2,5)*myfun(a^2+c*d, 5+6)
   I want to extraxt: a^2+c*d and  5+6

How should I do that in R?

Thank you!

Comment: Hi new user, please edit your question to provide a reproducible example, showing us what you've tried and the errors you are getting. What we want to be able to do is to cut and paste your example code into our R sessions, run it, reproduce the error, and then fix it to demonstrate what the corrected code looks like. It sounds like in your case, you may want to include a few test cases. Good luck and thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you be certain that your expression only contains a single list of terms in parentheses, then we can try using `sub` here:

```
exp <- "myfun(expr1, expr2)*expr3"
terms <- gsub("^[^(]*\\(([^)]+)\\).*$", "\\1", exp)
result <- strsplit(terms, ",\\s*")[[1]]
result

[1] "expr1" "expr2"
```